# Why is only one browser working on windows 10?

Tags: google-chrome, firefox, browser, opera

I currently have Firefox, Chrome and Opera installed (in that order).

At the moment I use Firefox/Opera for personal use and Chrome for work related stuff.

Firefox works like normal. Chrome and Opera however don't seem to load websites until after several times (sometimes never).

I don't know if it maybe a privacy setting or something, (like I couldn't figure out why my microphone wasn't working in Audacity and it was because I had stopped Windows 10 from allowing use of Microphone), however I cannot find any settings.

I have uninstalled and reinstalled all the browsers and ran in safemode, nothing seems to work.

What can I do to resolve this?

Comment: Try http://52.222.146.72 - if this works, it's a DNS related issue.

Comment: @davidbaumann And if it doesn't work? (I get a 403 error).

Comment: I guess it's a DNS related issue, as it connects successfully using the IP. The server does not know which site to display because you connected using the ip.

Comment: @davidbaumann I don't follow. You say if you *can* connect to the IP address it's a DNS related issue. Now the case is that one *can not* connect to that address and you again say that it is a DNS issue. Based on your first statement only succesfully connecting to the IP would signal a DNS issue. Unsu

Comment: Actually, your computer connects to the ip. Otherwise it could not show the 403 Error, but would show a timeout. So connecting to an IP directly works.

Comment: I get a 403 error.... so....